# Pandas: new rows using time windowed or shifted variables

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make time windows of my data in python, but I'm stuck on figuring out the steps to get there.  I know I can get to where I want by taking the data out of a dataframe and writing some messy for loops.  While I'm somewhat new to pandas, I'd like to figure out how to do it just using pandas operations.

To make clear what I mean, I have some data in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
              category   var1   var2
month
2010-01-01           A    0.2      1
2010-02-01           A    0.3      2      
2010-03-01           A    0.4      2
2010-04-01           A    0.5      1
2010-01-01           B    0.6      1
2010-02-01           B    0.7      2
2010-03-01           B    0.8      1
     .               .     .       . 
     .               .     .       . 
     .               .     .       .
```

My goal is to transform this data such that the rows are the "time windowed" versions of my original data.  What I'm trying to do is hard to put into words, so I'll give an example.  Say my time window width is N months, or for this example, 2 months.  I want the result to look like this:

```
category    current_var2    current_var1    previous_var1
       A               1             0.2              NaN
       A               2             0.3              0.2
       A               2             0.4              0.3
       A               1             0.5              0.4
       B               1             0.6              NaN
       B               2             0.7              0.6
       B               1             0.8              0.7
```

I've tried various combinations of pivot, shift, and groupby, but still can't coerce this output format.  Any suggestions?  I'm interested in solutions that will help me learn to use pandas more effectively.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and your month column is monthly already then you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html#pandas.Series.groupby) 'category' column and call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on 'var1' and pass function [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) and assign this back to your df:

```
In [32]:

df['previous_var1'] = df.groupby('category')['var1'].transform(pd.Series.shift)
df
Out[32]:
           category  var1  var2   previous_var1
month                                          
2010-01-01        A   0.2     1             NaN
2010-02-01        A   0.3     2             0.2
2010-03-01        A   0.4     2             0.3
2010-04-01        A   0.5     1             0.4
2010-01-01        B   0.6     1             NaN
2010-02-01        B   0.7     2             0.6
2010-03-01        B   0.8     1             0.7
```

Comment: wow, yup.  That's slick, thank you.  Didn't know of "transform".   Also my month column is monthly, not daily.  But your solution still works perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to shift the other direction while using `transform`? I tried `[...].transform(pd.Series.shift(-1)` and see `TypeError: shift() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Yes, `[...].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-1))`